# Error when installing Imagemagick with homebrew in OS X El Capitan

Tags: imagemagick

First of all I am completely new to homebrew. 
I want to install imagemagick and did this:

`brew install imagemagick`

but get this error:

`Error: An exception occured within a child process:
 RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config not present or broken
 Please reinstall pkg-config. Sorry :(`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like some files got moved around. Reinstall `pkg-config`, and if that doesn't work, reinstall homebrew.